# Как для Visual Basic .NET приложения сделать справку?

Tags: vb.net, ui, visual-basic

Так, что - бы по нажатию F1 открывалось окно с помощью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекстная справка для приложений .NET добавляется при помощи компонента [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.HelpProvider.aspx) из System.Windows.Forms. По ссылке приведен пример на VB.NET, как работать с компонентом. Если вкратце, то нужно для всех интересующих элементов определить подсказки

```
Me.HelpProviderX.SetHelpString(Me.TextBoxX, "Это подсказка.")
Me.HelpProviderX.SetShowHelp(Me.TextBoxX, True)
```

Файл справки связывается с приложением через свойство HelpNamespace

```
Me.HelpProviderX.HelpNamespace = "help.chm"
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, понял.